# Problems with siunitx package?

Tags: errors, siunitx

Once I use the `siunitx` package, this error message prompts:

> ```
> ! File ended while scanning use of \__siunitx_table_rewrite_create_aux:w.
>   <inserted text>
>   \par
>   <*> paper.tex
>   I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
>   to read past where you wanted me to stop.
>   I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
>   you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
>   ! Emergency stop.
>   <*> paper.tex
>   *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
>   Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>   21553 strings out of 494045
>   422667 string characters out of 3148364
>   448797 words of memory out of 3000000
>   24480 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
>   91950 words of font info for 94 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
>   715 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>   56i,1n,55p,726b,104s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
>   ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
> ```

**Here is my MWE.**

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{natbib} % for the bibliography
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{array} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdwtools/
\usepackage{eqparbox} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eqparbox/
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/
\usepackage{stfloats} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sttools/
\usepackage{url} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/misc/
\usepackage{siunitx}
% for TikZ drawing
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, positioning, fit}
\usepackage{color}
% for figure inclusion
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% for pseudocode
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{INPUT: }}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{OUTPUT: }}
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{
    Name1\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
    Name2\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
    Name3\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
    Name4\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}institute1\\ Email1}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}institute2\\ Email2}
}

holding assumption
HD algorithm
\SI{42.122}{\micro\tesla}
\footnote{National Geophysical Data Center http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me. Did you try deleting all files exept the .tex file?

Comment: If the MWE works, the please post something that does not. Otherwise we cannot help

Comment: @Chris  exactly, it compile well online as well. It just fails when added into my file. Strangely my file without these two line complies well as well!

Comment: @perfectionm1ng There must be some key difference between the demo and the real file: work through removing part of your real file at a time until you locate what it is.

Comment: Ok, what is the difference between your file and the MWE? In my experience its mostly forgotten brackets.

Comment: Which two lines put into what? You know, we are all out of crystal balls...

Comment: That is actually not how to use `siunitx`. You should instead `\SI{42.122}{\micro\tesla}`. This adds a little space between the number among other improvements.

Comment: @Chris  I have got the MWE that still causes the error. Please see updated aquestion.

Comment: @JosephWright  Thanks a lot for the advice. Done as told. Please see updated question.

Comment: @daleif  Sorry for the confusion. I have made the error MWE clear now. Please see the editted question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. +1, but more minimal/standard replace `IEEEtran` by `article`

Comment: @AndrewSwann I deleted my previous comment because I  noticed there was a different error.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng There is a lot you can remove and still get the same error. This is minimal: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{42.122}{\micro\tesla}
\end{document}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It is actually not minimal; you can remove `array`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Yes and no. After removing `array` you still get an error, but it is a different error than the one mentioned in the question. That's why I left it in.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Good point. I didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue here is the `mdwtab` package, which completely alters the tabular code from `array`. Within `siunitx`, the code attempts to be cross-compatible by not making too many assumptions, but `array` is very widely used and so is treated as a baseline.

To fix the issue, there are a couple of changes needed. First, you have to account for this altered table mechanism. Secondly, you need to also allow for an additional token that gets placed in the tabular cells by `mdwtab`. A patch looks something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__siunitx_table_rewrite_create:N #1
  {
    \newcolumntype {#1} [1] []
      {
        > { \__siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn #1 {##1} }
        c
        < { \__siunitx_table_print: }
      }

  }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__siunitx_table_collect_not_braced:N #1
  {
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNF #1 \tex_ignorespaces:D
      {
        \token_if_eq_meaning:NNF #1 \tex_unskip:D
          {
            \token_if_eq_meaning:NNF #1 \tab@setcr
              { \__siunitx_table_collect_not_braced_aux_i:N #1 }
          }
      }
    \__siunitx_table_collect_next:
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 2.2]}
  1.23 \\
  45.6
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'll look to incorporate this into the next `siunitx` release: there may be a few more wrinkles to iron out, but that should cover the basics.