# Clash between siunitx and mdwtab

Tags: errors, siunitx, mdwtools

I just had the following error after including `mdwtab` while using `siunitx` inside a `tabular` block:

```
! Extra \fi.
\@maybe@unskip ...skip \m@ne \lastskip \relax \fi 
                                                  
l.18   1.0 &
             0.0 \\ \hline
```

Apparently, this is [not the first clash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145769/problems-with-siunitx-package) between these packages. Is there any "easy" workaround for this issue? I have to include `mdwtab`, so if there is no workaround, I will need to use something other than `siunitx` for number alignment in tables like `dcolumn`.

### Complete example

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Compilation fails if mdwtab is included
\usepackage{mdwtab}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=4.1]|}
  \hline
  1.0 \\ \hline
  2.0 \\ \hline
  3.0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

% The problem happens in there
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=4.1]|c|}
  \hline
  1.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
  2.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
  3.0 & 0.0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

### Package versions

> Package: siunitx 2015/01/21 v2.6e A comprehensive (SI) units package
>
> Package: mdwtab 1998/04/28 1.9 Table typesetting with style
>
> Package: array 2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `mdwtab` is incompatible with a lot of things, mit even be just `array` that is the problem. It has not been updated for a long time, what particular feature from `mdwtab` do you need that is not provided by other packages?

Comment: The LaTeX template for the paper I'm writing *highly recommends* to use it, hence my reluctance to remove the include.

Comment: Don't mention that evil word... (How much do you trust the template and when was it last updated?) Now seriously, if you don't see a difference when removing `mdwtab` you are probably good to go. Also note that the doc of `mdwtabs` states "The `mdwtab` environment is not 100% compatible with the `tabular` environment found in LaTeX2ε".

Comment: Well, apparently the 2015 `IEEEtran` template still mentions it (cf. [bare_adv.tex](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/?lang=en)), but the include is commented by default. A contributor of the paper uncommented it in a totally unrelated commit, so I guess removing it and quickly checking that this does not break the layout of the paper is the smartest/safest route.

Comment: Isn't this once again a case of  the template not having been updated for 5+ years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another special-case macro that needs to be detected by `siunitx`. Fix for the present:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \@ifpackageloaded { mdwtab }
      {
        \cs_set_protected:Npn \__siunitx_table_collect_not_braced:N #1
          {
            \token_if_eq_meaning:NNF #1 \tex_ignorespaces:D
              {
                \token_if_eq_meaning:NNF #1 \tex_unskip:D
                  {
                    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNF #1 \tab@setcr
                      {
                        \token_if_eq_meaning:NNF #1 \@maybe@unskip
                          { \__siunitx_table_collect_not_braced_aux_i:N #1 }
                      }  
                  }
              }
            \__siunitx_table_collect_next:
          }
      }
      { }
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Well, that solves it, and I would clearly not have been able to fix that. Thanks!